# Удаление экземпляра класса, переданного в качестве аргумента в другой класс

Tags: c#

Суть моего задания в том, чтобы придумать ситуацию, когда будет необходим финализатор. Я хотел сделать пример с файловой системой. В класс передается ссылка на экземпляр класса `FileStream` и, по идее, при удалении моего класса должен закрыться поток. Вот мой пример: есть класс, который в конструкторе принимает в качестве аргумента экземпляр класса `FileStream`:

```
class MyClass
{
    FileStream _fileStream;
    public MyClass(ref FileStream filestream)
    {
        this._fileStream =  filestream;
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Object destroy.");
        _fileStream.Close();
        _fileStream.Dispose();
        _fileStream = null;
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Основная программа:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\..\..\folder\";
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(path + "Text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    MyClass file = new ChildClass(fileStream);

    file = null;
    GC.Collect();

  //  fileStream.Close();   С этой строкой работает без исключения
    FileStream fileStream2 = new FileStream(path + "Text.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

При создании экземпляра `fileStream2` происходит исключение, о том, что файл занят другим процессом. Почему не работает передача по ссылке? Почему так получается, что `_fileStream` и `filestream` - это два разных экземпляра, указывающие на разные ссылки? Ключевое слово `ref` здесь в качестве эксперимента. Ведь экземпляры ссылочных типов и так передаются по ссылке.

Comment: а строчка выводится? `Console.WriteLine("Object destroy.");`?

Comment: Да, "Object destroy" выводится.

Comment: откуда ты знаешь, что он выводится _до_ того, как идет присвоение fileStream2?

Comment: [A correctly-written program cannot assume that finalizers will ever run at any point prior to program termination.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100809-00/?p=13203)

Answer (score 3):

Наличие `ref` рядом с типом параметра говорит о том, что в функции этот параметр можно переназначить и это переназначение скажется на вызываемом коде.
В Вашем случае такого переназначения не происходит, т.к. нет присваивания вида:

```
filestream = нечто;
```

в теле функции, принимающей `ref` параметр. Т.е. Вы просто не использовали то, что предоставляет `ref`. Поэтому даже после вызова:

```
_fileStream = null;
```

в финализаторе, остается ссылка `fileStream`, связанная с открытым файлом. Это и приводит к упомянутому исключению.

Если Вы измените конструктор до следующего вида:

```
public MyClass(ref FileStream filestream)
{
    this._fileStream = filestream;
    filestream = null; // изменяем ref-параметр
}
```

то ошибка должна уйти.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> _fileStream.Close();
> _fileStream.Dispose();
> ```

Это неправильно. Во-первых, managed-объекты сборщик мусора соберёт сам, так что неизвестно, жив ли ещё объект. Такое должен делать метод Dispose, а не финализатор. Во-вторых, Close и Dispose - это одно и то же. Нет смысла вызывать их оба.

> ```
> GC.Collect();
> ```

А это вообще жесть. Он сам в курсе, когда ему запускаться. К тому же, он своё дело и так делает - мы же в финализаторе.

PS: Советую почитать статью http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2011/09/dispose-pattern.html

Comment: Вы наверное не совсем меня поняли. Я понимаю, что не надо вмешиваться в работу сборщика мусора. Но есть такое задание - показать случай, когда необходим финализатор. Поэтому в примере я сам обнуляю ссылку и вызываю GC, чтобы знать точно, когда этот объект удалится. А то что там идут подряд Close(); Dispose(); и GC.Collect() - это для того, чтобы показать, что не один из этих способов не очистил поток.

Comment: @raskopin, нет, перечитай ответ.